# Autorun Chrome kiosk app when Chrome OS starts up

Tags: google-chrome-app, kiosk-mode, google-chrome-os

When Chrome OS ready, need to click 'App' button and then select the kiosk app, but I want to launch it automatically on startup.

How to set that up?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Answer found here: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chromebook-central/XTqYPQfZmNc

> Please follow the steps below to put Chromebook into Kiosk mode.
>
> 1. Wipe Data on Chromebook (Follow [this link](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/1360642) for instructions).
> 2. After wipe is completed, you will be at the welcome screen. (Input your network information, but DO NOT LOGIN to the Chromebook)
> 3. At the login screen, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> and enable Kiosk mode.
> 4. Login into the Chromebook.
> 5. Open a new tab in Chrome, and enter `chrome://extensions` in the address bar (also known as the omnibox). Click enter.
> 6. Check the box next to Developer Mode.
> 7. Click Add kiosk application, and enter the ID of the Kiosk App you'd like to enable.
> 8. Highlight the Kiosk App and select "auto launch".
> 9. Press Enter or click Done.
> 10. Reboot and when asked, enable app for Kiosk mode.
> 11. Now the app will auto launch each time you reboot.
> 12. To Turn off Kiosk Mode, begin by rebooting the Chromebook. While the device is starting up, press the keyboard shortcut
>       <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to interrupt the process and return to the login screen.

Good luck!

Comment: I have enabled the kiosk mode on a device (not managed, 2017). But how can I configure the app ? (Chrome Sign Builder)

Comment: This answer still works for me. I just configured 4 chromeboxes and 2 chromebits using this method.

Comment: Problem is have with this is step 12. After I enable kioskmode i can disable it, unless i put in a recovery disk and wipe the whole device....

Comment: Step 10 doesn't work that way on my Chromebit. No opportunity to "enable app for Kiosk mode" at that point. Need to launch app from launchbar at bottom, in a menu called "Apps". Requires me to keep a mouse or keyboard plugged in when rebooting (e.g., on power failure). Kiosk mode is working, as I can launch (with mouse) without logging in. But I want the kiosk app to run automatically.

Comment: @MarcRochkind This is from forever and some ago, I know, but did you ever figure out if this is possible? We have 20+ existing boxes that were setup and we got this to work. I just tried to set a few more up, it required me to update the OS, and now it doesn't seem to let me auto-start.

Comment: I was unable to come up with any way to do it, but haven't tested in the last 6 months to see if a Chrome update has changed anything.